Reference another worksheet using the .formula2 function
I have a spreadsheet where I need formulas exposed to allow users to trace calculations and/or origins to the numbers being provided in the report.
.Range("A" & i).Formula = "=COUNTIFS('SpreadsheetA'!J:J,'TEST'!B" & i & ",'SpreadsheetA'!D:D,"" > ""&'Control'!C5)"

Everything works except the reference to the test sheet and the control sheet, where the output removes both apostrophes.
RESULT:
=COUNTIFS('SpreadsheetA'!J:J,TEST!B2,'SpreadsheetA'!D:D," > "&Control!C5)


Only sheet names with spaces need quotes, so they're removed if there are no spaces.  The same thing will happen if you enter the formula manually.

Thank you. If that's the case, the formula appears to be picking up correctly but the output on my end does not match what I would expect. Thanks for the help.

Possibly use ... Control!C$5.... You don't need a sheet reference for the sheet defined by .Range(...)..., the one you're writing to (TEST). Also, there is no need to loop i.e. e.g. .Range("A2:ALastRow").Formula = "... B2 ...".

... & ",'SpreadsheetA'!D:D,"" > ""&'Control'!C5)" should be ... & ",'SpreadsheetA'!D:D, "">"" & 'Control'!C5)"  (no spaces around >)

.Range("A" & i).Formula = "=COUNTIFS('SpreadsheetA'!J:J,'TEST'!B" & i & _
                           ",'SpreadsheetA'!D:D,"" > ""&'Control'!C5)"

should be
.Range("A" & i).Formula = "=COUNTIFS('SpreadsheetA'!J:J,'TEST'!B" & i & _
                           ",'SpreadsheetA'!D:D,"">"" & 'Control'!C5)"

You can't have those spaces around the ">"

Nice catch. Don't you think that the row of C5 should be locked?

@VBasic2008 -  I guess that also!  So ... & 'Control'!C$5)"

...but would be OK as C5 if the formula isn't going to be filled down.

Sorry, being dumb.

Not at all - with only one line there's no way to know the next line isn't a "fill down" operation....

Thank you. Amazing catch here as this was actually the issue I was having where the > operations was not being done.

I tried it using the attached workbook and the below code, if worked for me:
Sub test()
   Dim i As Integer
   i = 3
   ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Formula = "=COUNTIFS('SpreadsheetA'!J:J,TEST!B" & i & ",'SpreadsheetA'!D:D,"" > ""&Control!C5)"
End Sub

See attached images for the data.





It worked for me should be a comment. The OP in his comment already stated, that it works but not return the required result for him.

As shown in the images this gives the required results, btw I can't add  images/longer code in comments.
